# Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

New to spring. I'm getting the following exception being caught:

```
2012-06-14 16:20:57,719 [http-8080-6] ERROR com.nimchip.lmu.data.service.impl.CoworkerServiceImpl - Error sending mail:
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp. Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: Unable to locate provider for protocol: smtp
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:400) ~[spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306) ~[spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296) ~[spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.nimchip.lmu.data.service.impl.CoworkerServiceImpl.genUpdateNomination(CoworkerServiceImpl.java:224) ~[lmu-dataaccess-1.0.0.jar:na]
    at com.nimchip.lmu.controller.coworkerNom.CoworkerController.genUpdateNomination(CoworkerController.java:312)
```

I have a mail-config.xml which is registered in my web.xml. Here it is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="10.30.137.190"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I should be able to log anonymously to the mail server specified, so no user or password needed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Do you have the `mail.jar` and `activation.jar`in your classpath?

These classes should provide the smtp-provider.

If you are using maven, simply add this to your pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Ok i'm pretty sure I don't. But how do I add them using maven? Do i just put something as a dependency? I don't know a lot of intricacies between maven and spring yet I was tasked on learning them sorry.

Comment: Yes you can just add them with maven. Search for mail and activation in your repository.

Comment: Just in case anyone is reading this: they replaced javax.mail with [com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.5.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.5.2)

Comment: For people using OSGi: upgrade to the newest version (https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release): javax.mail + javax.activation do not work nicely with OSGi due to their classloading mechanisms. More info here:  https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bndtools-users/dWRLwQl1TMs/1c3O9HC8CwAJ

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using mailapi as artifact id and that was causing the issue.
I replaced 
`<artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>` with
`<artifactId>mail</artifactId>` and it worked fine